# How to trim a string to its last four characters?

Tags: javascript

I know there are methods to remove characters from the beginning and from the end of a string in Javascript. What I need is trim a string in such a way that only the last 4 characters remain.

For eg:

```
ELEPHANT -> HANT

1234567 -> 4567
```

Comment: You mean `'elephant'.substr(-4)`?

Comment: do you maybe want a substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) will work

```
var str = "ELEPHANT";
console.log(str.slice(-4));
//=> HANT
```

For, numbers, you will have to convert to strings first

```
var str = (1234567).toString();
console.log(str.slice(-4));
//=> 4567
```

---

**FYI** `.slice` returns a new string, so if you want to update the value of `str`, you would have to

```
str = str.slice(-4);
```

Comment: just tried it and it works. @Nikhil Actually i just need to display the last 4. Not required to change the actual string.

Comment: I added a note either way :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr` method of javascript:

```
var str="Elephant";
var n=str.substr(-4);
alert(n);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `slice` to do this

```
string.slice(start,end)
```

Comment: down-vote as slice with negative number is better

Comment: @user2310289 This answer didn't make any assumptions about what `start` would be ... it *could* be negative.

Comment: Maybe an example can be given to show how this would be used

Answer (score -1):

lets assume you use jQuery + javascript as well.

Lets have a label in the HTML page with id="lblTest".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc() {
      val lblTest = $("[id*=lblTest]");
      if (lblTest) {
      var str = lblTest.text();
      // this is your needed functionality
      alert(str.substring(str.length-4, str.length));
      } else {
      alert('does not exist');
      }
    }
</script>
```

Edit: so the core part is -

```
var str = "myString";
var output = str.substring(str.length-4, str.length);
```

Comment: What was the reason for down-vote? I'd like to understand...

Comment: it wasn't me, but what happens if str is < 4 chars in length?